# Connecting to website as a function - passing Objects

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a side project that will interact with a website.  I want to have this run on a timer...every 10 minutes, I want this program to connect to the site, and check for an update.  The code below works in that it will let me connect to an existing IE window that is already on the site...and if one is not open, it will start a new IE window, and then login.

```
Public Sub ConnectToSite()
  Dim Idx As Integer, Found As Integer
  Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
  Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
  Dim bOpen As Boolean
  Dim wb As Workbook

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
  bOpen = False
  Idx = 0
  For Each objIE In shellWins
    Debug.Print objIE.LocationName
    If objIE.LocationName = "Testing" Then
      bOpen = True
      Found = Idx
    End If
    Idx = Idx + 1
  Next objIE
  If bOpen Then
    Set objIE = shellWins.Item(Found)
  Else
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    With objIE
      .Visible = False
      .navigate "https://justtesting.com/"
      Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
      Logon objIE
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

I have tested this part and it works.  My question is...how should I go about making this a function so that later when I have other timers running macros - or other subs that need to connect - I don't duplicate this code?

Should I pass a nonexistent pointer to objIE to this function ByRef and have it Set inside?  Should the function return the object?

```
Public Function ConnectToSite(ByRef objIE as InternetExplorer) as Boolean
'Code from above
  ConnectToSite = True 'Either way we would connect
End Function

Public Sub Main()
  Dim IE As InternetExplorer
  'In main sub
  If ConnectToSite(IE) Then
    'Do some stuff
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Depends what you actually need and prefer. I'd make it parameterless and `As InternetExplorer`, and instead of a `Boolean` I'd return `Nothing` on failure, or a valid `InternetExplorer` object reference on success.

Comment: Would it be worth it to make it late binding instead?  If so, how would you pass that object?

Comment: Late binding adds overhead. You don't need late-binding unless you're planning to distribute your code to users that might be running different versions of the libraries you're referencing. Other than that, makes no difference - you just return an `Object` instead of an `InternetExplorer`... which makes an arguably good point in favor of passing it as a `ByRef` parameter, so you can give it a meaningful name (e.g. `browser`), instead of scratching your head looking at an `Object`-returning function.